# using node js spawn with quotes will cause quotes to be escaped

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, child-process

I'm trying to use child_process spawn function to execute a batch file.
the problem is if i send it an arg with quotes (i.e.  `"a  b"` ) it will escape the quotes running command with `"\"a" "b\""`

any way to disable this quoting and pass string as is ?

code snippet

```
var spawnFunc = require('child_process').spawn;
var args = getProgArgs();
return spawnFunc("run.bat",args,{cwd: automationPath});
```

Comment: what is in `getProgArgs()` ?

Comment: Are the quotes really part of the argument, or is the _actual_ argument that you want to pass `a b`?

Comment: @PA. getProgArgs() is a function that passes a user given list of args

Comment: @robertklep yes, i want the string unaltered, why is node changing my output ?